# Button Triggerevent IsPressed isn't working

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, triggers, background-color

I want to change the background color of my two `Button`s in the `StackPanel` when they got clicked. In the `Window.Ressources` I implement two triggers `IsMouseOver` and `IsPressed`. The event `IsMouseOver` is working and I get the hover-effect that I wanted, but the event `IsPressed` is not working. I don't see the problem, can anybody help me?

```
<Window x:Class="Einstellungen_awintaONE.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Einstellungen_awintaONE"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="awintaONE Einstellungen" Height="500" Width="850">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="_ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#585757"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#BBBBBB"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Name="_Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,0,0,0" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="_Border" Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="_Border" Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                                <Setter  Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="180" Name="Navigation" />
            <ColumnDefinition  Name="Einstellungen"/>          
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        
        <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="#BBBBBB">
            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>            
                <StackPanel   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" >
                    <Button Content="Systeminformationen" Style="{DynamicResource _ButtonStyle}"  Height="30" />                    
                    <Button Content="Einstellungsassistent" Style="{DynamicResource _ButtonStyle}" Height="30"  />
                </StackPanel>                
            </Grid>
        </Border>               
    </Grid>    
</Window>
```

Comment: try set normal Background: `<Border Name="_Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">`

Answer (score 0):

The *Mouse Over* and *Pressed* triggers work just fine, but you do not see it, because in both triggers you assign the same background color, hence there is no visual difference between both states.

Apart from that you do not bind the `Background` property of your `Border` to the templated parent, which means that your setters for the for the background in the style (`#BBBBBB`) are not applied. This is the inital *Static* state of the button.

It only appears to be right, because as it is the border does not have a background and you see through it to the background of the parent `Grid`. To fix that, add a [`TemplateBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to your `Border`.

```
<Border Name="_Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
```

You could do the same for the `Foreground` property, although this one also works as it is.

---

Update for your comments. If you want the colors to stay after the button was clicked, meaning it stays clicked, then you use the wrong control. Use a [`ToggleButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton?view=net-5.0) instead.

```
<Style x:Key="_ToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#585757"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="#BBBBBB"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Border Name="_Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
               <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,0,0,0" />
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                  <Setter TargetName="_Border" Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                  <Setter TargetName="_Border" Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                  <Setter  Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                  <Setter TargetName="_Border" Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                  <Setter  Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

```
<StackPanel   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" >
   <ToggleButton Content="Systeminformationen" Style="{DynamicResource _ToggleButtonStyle}"  Height="30" />                    
   <ToggleButton Content="Einstellungsassistent" Style="{DynamicResource _ToggleButtonStyle}" Height="30"  />
</StackPanel>
```

I see your next question coming, how to toggle the button again when clicking a different button? The answer is you do not. You are using the wrong control, because your problem is a different one I guess. This is most likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

If you want to create a sidebar or something similar, use a [`Selector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector?view=net-5.0) control like a [`TabControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol?view=net-5.0) with [`TabStripPlacement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol?view=net-5.0) set to `Left` or a`ListBox` with an appropriate style.

Comment: Ok thank you, but i want that the changed background color and foreground color stays after i click on the button. How can i do that?